# How to force bdutil command to run as root?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-hadoop

I am starting a Google Compute Engine VM from an App Engine application.  The start-up scripts for the GCE VM run python scripts which, in turn, make os.system calls to bdutil commands, *e.g.*,

```
os.system("bdutil --bucket <BUCKET> --num_workers 1 "
          "--env_var_files hadoop2_env.sh --default_fs hdfs "
          "--zone us-central1-b --prefix <NAME> --force deploy")
```

I have found it necessary to run these scripts as root, *e.g.*,

```
sudo python script.py
```

The `--force deploy` command option works as expected, *i.e.*,  The shell terminal shows:

```
Deploy cluster with following settings?
....
(y/n) y
```

However, another prompt is included:

```
Are you sure you want to run the command as root? (y/n)
```

I have found I need to execute these scripts as root, but I am also executing them remotely and cannot respond to terminal prompts.

How can I force the execution of this bdutil command without responding to the final prompt?  Modification of the bdutil source code is not a viable option.

Comment: Apologies for the delay; for future reference, adding the `google-hadoop` tag may reach the Hadoop team more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report, this is a bug in `bdutil`, and in normal circumstances we should indeed apply the `-f` or `--force` flags to all confirmation prompts, not just the standard deploy/delete prompts. I've filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/issues/31 to track this issue.

In the meantime, you should be able to workaround this using the linux `yes` command, which is commonly used as an ad-hoc `--force` flag for commands which don't include such a flag directly:

```
os.system("yes | bdutil --bucket <BUCKET> --num_workers 1 "
          "--env_var_files hadoop2_env.sh --default_fs hdfs "
          "--zone us-central1-b --prefix <NAME> --force deploy")
```